# Can Ubuntu work on a Pentium T4400 CPU?

Tags: dell, laptop

I have a Dell Inspiron INSP1440 laptop with a Pentium T4400 dual-core CPU. I need to know if Ubuntu 14.04 (or any version) will work on it before I burn Ubuntu to a disk.

Answer (score 1):

yes why not it will work smoothly but i recommend to have atleast 2-4 gb of ram on your pc